# RecyclerView и wrap_content. Как анимировать высоту RecyclerView при удалении итема?

Tags: android, recyclerview

[image: Лэйаут после нажатия MEASURE + REQUESTLAYOUT, ничем не отличается от первоначального]

[image: Лэйаут после нажатия MEASURE]

Итак, имеется `Layout` с `RecycleView`, высота - `wrap_content`, ширина - `match_parent`. При нажатии "remove" - удаляется второй итем. При этом хочу анимировать изменение высоты `RecyclerView`. `TransitionManager` на нем не отрабатывает, пробую сделать с помощью `preDrawListener` и `ValueAnimator`. Проблема в том, что нужно узнать конечный размер высоты `RecyclerView`. для этого вызываю `measure()` и `getMeasuredHeight()`, потом анимирую. И все в принципе анимируется, но итемы в начале анимации дергаются. Как я потом выяснил это происходит при вызове `measure()`. Ведут они себя так, будто ширина `RecyclerView` бесконечна (растягиваются  за экран, как видно на скринах). Как убрать этот эффект или как по-другому анимировать изменение высоты `RecyclerView`?

Прикладываю код.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int itemCount = 5;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private int recyclerViewLastHeight;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        Button remove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove);
        Button measure = (Button) findViewById(R.id.measure);
        Button requestlayout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestlayout);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rv.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter() {
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                return new ViewHolder(view) {
                    @Override
                    public String toString() {
                        return super.toString();
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return itemCount;
            }
        });

        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                animateRecyclerView();
                if (itemCount-- < 2) {
                    rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                    itemCount = 5;
                } else {
                    rv.getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(1);
                }

            }
        });

        measure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rv.measure(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }
        });
        requestlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rv.measure(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                rv.requestLayout();
            }
        });
    }

    private void animateRecyclerView() {
        rv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            int mFrames = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                switch (mFrames++) {
                    case 0:
                        recyclerViewLastHeight = rv.getHeight();
                        rv.measure(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        rv.requestLayout();
                        rv.invalidate();
                        int height = rv.getMeasuredHeight();

                        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator
                                .ofInt(recyclerViewLastHeight, height)
                                .setDuration(300);
                        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                                rv.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                                rv.requestLayout();
                            }
                        });
                        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                mFrames = 0;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
                        });
                        animator.start();

                        recyclerViewLastHeight = height;

                        return true;
                    case 1:
                        return true;
                }
                rv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="ru.xmn.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="remove"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/measure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="measure"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/requestlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="measure + requestlayout"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="ru.xmn.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

и [ссылочку на гит](https://github.com/xemniz/RecyclerViewProblem), чтобы можно было быстро скачать и посмотреть.

**UPD**

Прошу читать внимательнее! Я хочу анимировать изменение высоты `RecyclerView`, высота которого `wrap_content`, при удалении айтема она уменьшается скачками. Вот [статья об этом](https://medium.com/@elye.project/recyclerview-supported-wrap-content-not-quite-f04a942ce624#.dhto2yp8p).

Comment: Непонятно, что вы анимируете. Метод `notifyItemRemoved` анимирует исчезновение итема сжиманием по высоте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема все таки решилась с помощью `TransitionManager`, без велосипеда. Нужно было только исключить `RecyclerView` и `Item'ы` из анимаций, иначе работает некорректно. Следующий метод вызывается перед каждым `notify`. Под `RecyclerView` у меня кнопка, чтобы она не наезжала на `Item'ы` поставил задержку.

```
private void animateRecyclerView() {
    transition = new AutoTransition();
    transition.excludeChildren(DataBindingViewHolder.class, true);
    transition.excludeChildren(RecyclerView.class, true);
    transition.setDuration(500).setStartDelay(1000);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.Root, transition);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для удаления итема из `RecyclerView` используйте

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Он сам выполнит анимацию исчезновения итема сужением высоты. Ваш велосипед стерите.

**UPD**

Как пишут  [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview)  `wrap_content` в `RecyclerView` работает корректно в версии библиотеки

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

Вот ещё нашёл [статью на Хабре](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/255397/)

Comment: хочу анимировать изменение height ресайклервью, ясно же написал. итем удаляется, ресайклер не на весь экран, height скачет.

Comment: @Николай Конорев, обновил ответ

Comment: Да, написано что корректно, я тоже гуглил. А в статье, которую прикрепил к вопросу есть сомнения по этому поводу. Прошу Вас, прочитайте внимательнее вопрос! в статье на хабре тоже нет анимации высоты списка при удалении.

Comment: @Николай Конорев, фух, сдаюсь :)

Answer (score 0):

Класс `RecyclerView` имеет встроенные анимации на удаление,добавление, перемещение и изменение айтема или группы айтемов: методы `notifyItemRemoved()`, `notifyItemInserted()`, `notifyItemMoved()`, `notifyItemChanged()` и соответствующие с *Range* для группы: `notifyItemRangeRemoved()` и тд.

Если стандартная анимация вас не устраивает, вы можете подключить собственную через вложенный класс [`RecyclerView.ItemAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html).

```
RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new MyItemAnimator();
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
```

Устанавливает собственную реализацию анимаций в список, где вы можете переопределить анимации добавления, удаления, перемещения и изменения, используя соответствующие флаги состояния или методы класса.  Так же класс позволяет анимировать и виджеты на айтеме.
Для вызова соответствующих анимаций вы должны использовать методы удаления, добавления и тд., перечисленные выше.

Comment: я в курсе, анимации внутри отрабатывают, но при удалении итема скачет высота ресайклервью. https://medium.com/@elye.project/recyclerview-supported-wrap-content-not-quite-f04a942ce624#.qgvdecnn8

Comment: @НиколайКонорев из вашего вопроса никак не следует, что вы что то об этом знаете, слепив вместо предусмотренной функциональности какой-то костыль

Comment: функциональности нет, посмотрите статью, высота списка просто скачет. предложите мне другой велосипед, с радостью приму